# How to change image source with effect using fadin

Tags: jquery

```
$('#main').attr("src", src).load(function() {
  $('#main').fadeIn(2000);
```

});

I want to change image with another but do not want to use first fadeout then fadein.
I do not want to disappear first image then show another.  Need to change the image while the first exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk how to do it with one image, but if you create another img tag you could do it.

You need the following basic html:

```
<div id="cycler">
    <img class="active" src="image1.jpg" alt="My image" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="My image" />     
</div>
```

Here’s the necessary css – just to show the z-index and positioning – you’ll need to add some more to position as required. Depending on your layout you may also need to set the height and width on #cycler to match your images:

```
#cycler{position:relative;}
#cycler img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
#cycler img.active{z-index:3}
```

And here’s the javascript:

```
function cycleImages(){
  var $active = $('#cycler .active');
  var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
  $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
      $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
  });
}
```